# Android Smack XMPP stanza listener : Missing stanza attribute

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

This is stanza that create from api :

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to="+60123333xxx@xxxx.xxxx.my/84947029xxx52245593xxx" from="7xxxa-3cd4-44c6-b5xxxxe5d3@xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.my">
    <x xmlns="jabber:x:conference" reason="new group chat : mucduke" jid="7xxxa-3cd4-44c6-b5xxxxe5d3@xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.my"></x>
    <body>new group chat : mucduke</body>
</message>
```

I use connection.addAsyncStanzaListener(stanzaListener, stanzaFilter) in android to get the stanza but atribute 'reason' and body element if missing from stanza. Can anyone help me why this happen?

Answer (score 2):

use following `StanzaTypeFilter` for add `addSyncStanzaListener`

```
 StanzaTypeFilter filter = new StanzaTypeFilter(Message.class);

    mStanzaListener = new StanzaListener() {
        @Override
        public void processPacket(Stanza stanza) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException {
                onMessageReceived(stanza);
        }
    };
    connection.addSyncStanzaListener(mStanzaListener, filter);
```

get `stanza` onMessageReceived

```
public void onMessageReceived(Stanza stanza) {

  if(stanza instanceof Message){
      Message msg= (Message) stanza;
      msg.getBody();
      ...
      ...
      }
  }
```